# Installing Kubernetes on Ubuntu - connection to the server was refused on reboot

Tags: kubernetes

I can install Kubernetes successfully on a Ubuntu 16 server, and get the master node into a Ready status. But if I reboot/restart, I get the error message in the title when I try to use `KUBECTL`.

Do I need to put the following commands given when I originally ran `KUBEADM INIT` into my profile to persist?

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

I was following the recipe in the *O'Reilly Kubernetes Cookbook*, together with using Google's K8S docs and Serverfault.

I can successfully get all the system pods running, and I can successfully get both a master and a single worker running as Ready. But they don't persist over a reboot.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-k8s-master                      1/1       Running   0          1m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-master            1/1       Running   0          2m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-master   1/1       Running   0          2m
kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-phphd            3/3       Running   0          3m
kube-system   kube-proxy-25mtq                     1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-master            1/1       Running   0          2m
kube-system   weave-net-rfb6z                      2/2       Running   0          50s

NAME          STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8s-master    Ready      master    9m        v1.10.3
k8s-worker1   Ready     <none>     14s       v1.10.3
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if your cluster is up and running:

```
$ ps aux | grep apiserver
$ ps aux | grep etcd
$ docker ps
```

You should see all necessary kubernetes processes running like `kube-proxy`, `kube-apiserver`, `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler`, `etcd`.

If cluster is ready, you can try to access `kube-apiserver` using `kubectl` tool.

By default, [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) takes its configuration from file `$HOME/.kube/config`

Default behavior can be changed by setting environment variable `KUBECONFIG`.
The `kubectl` read all configuration files listed in this variable and merge their configuration settings.
This way you can have the configuration for several clusters in separate files for easy maintenance.
In this case you should set `KUBECONFIG` variable in user profile, to be sure it has correct value after next login.

The other way to use specific config file is to set `--kubeconfig` argument in the command line

```
$ kubectl --kubeconfig config_file_path <other_command_line_arguments>
```

You can check available configuration (sensitive information will be suppressed) by running following command:

```
# kubectl config view
```

There is a  possibility to configure multiple context in one config file and to switch the context by specifying its name in command line. It is useful if you are managing several clusters (or different service accounts for the same cluster) using the same user account.

```
$ kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo use-context exp-scratch <other_command_line_arguments>
```

Check out the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) for details.

When you create a cluster with the command `kubeadm init` , it adds the connection configuration for the `kubectl` to the file `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

```
-rw-------   1 root root 5446 May 1 11:11 admin.conf
```

You can specify it as `kubectl` config file directly if you are using root account.
To use it with different user account, you need to copy it to user's `$HOME/.kube/config` file and make it accessible by user.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

It's enough to do it only once for each user's account which you plan to use for cluster management.
This is a regular file and it doesn't disappear after reboot, so you should still be able to access Kubernetes cluster running `kubectl` command.

If you reset the cluster with `kubeadm reset` and create it again, you need to update your `kubectl` connection configuration in the user profile, because previous cluster credentials will not work with new cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't checked the logs. Ubuntu 16.04 logs via systemd, so when I remember to check the logs via journalctl, it was clear immediately that Kubernetes was complaining that the swap was enabled. On the original install, I'd disabled the swap on each server - but I hadn't amended the /etc/fstab to disable the swap permanently.